# How to benchmark unit tests in Python without adding any code

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, benchmarking

I have a Python project with a bunch of tests that have already been implemented, and I'd like to begin benchmarking them so I can compare performance of the code, servers, etc over time.  Locating the files in a manner similar to Nose was no problem because I have "test" in the names of all my test files anyway.  However, I'm running into some trouble in attempting to dynamically execute these tests.

As of right now, I'm able to run a script that takes a directory path as an argument and returns a list of filepaths like this:

```
def getTestFiles(directory):
    fileList = []
    print "Searching for 'test' in " + directory
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(directory)):
        # throw error
        raise InputError(directory, "Not a valid directory")
    else:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            #print files
            for f in files:
                if "test" in f and f.endswith(".py"):
                    fileList.append(os.path.join(root, f))
    return fileList

# returns a list like this:
# [  'C:/Users/myName/Desktop/example1_test.py',
#    'C:/Users/myName/Desktop/example2_test.py',
#    'C:/Users/myName/Desktop/folder1/example3_test.py',
#    'C:/Users/myName/Desktop/folder2/example4_test.py'...  ]
```

The issue is that these files can have different syntax, which I'm trying to figure out how to handle.  For example:

**TestExampleOne:**

```
import dummy1
import dummy2
import dummy3

class TestExampleOne(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # set up

    def test_one(self):
        # test stuff
    def test_two(self):
        # test stuff
    def test_three(self):
        # test stuff

    # etc...
```

**TestExampleTwo:**

```
import dummy1
import dummy2
import dummy3

def setup(self):
    try:
        # config stuff
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)

def test_one():
    # test stuff
def test_two():
    # test stuff
def test_three():
    # test stuff

# etc...
```

**TestExampleThree:**

```
import dummy1
import dummy2
import dummy3

def setup(self):
    try:
        # config stuff
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)

class TestExampleTwo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        # test stuff
    def test_two(self):
        # test stuff
    # etc...

class TestExampleThree(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        # test stuff
    def test_two(self):
        # test stuff
    # etc...

# etc...
```

I would really like to be able to write one module that searches a directory for every file containing "test" in its name, and then executes every unit test in each file, providing execution time for each test.  I think something like NodeVisitor is on the right track, but I'm not sure.  Even an idea of where to start would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Not quite what you ask for, but related, is [vbench](http://www.onerussian.com/tmp/numpy-vbench/). It runs a set of benchmarks across version control. Note that tests may change what they do over time.

Comment: find <test_directory> -name '\*test\*.py' | while read t; do time $t; done

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`nose`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test runner would help to [discover the tests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html), setup/teardown functions and methods.

[`nose-timer`](https://github.com/mahmoudimus/nose-timer) plugin would help with benchmarking:

> A timer plugin for nosetests that answers the question: how much time
>   does every test take?

---

Demo:

- imagine you have a package named `test_nose` with the following scripts inside:

  - `test1.py`:

    ```
    import time
    import unittest

    class TestExampleOne(unittest.TestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            cls.value = 1

        def test_one(self):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.assertEqual(1, self.value)
    ```
  - `test2.py`:

    ```
    import time

    value = None

    def setup():
        global value
        value = 1

    def test_one():
        time.sleep(2)
        assert value == 1
    ```
  - `test3.py`:

    ```
    import time
    import unittest

    value = None

    def setup():
        global value
        value = 1

    class TestExampleTwo(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_one(self):
            time.sleep(3)
            self.assertEqual(1, value)

    class TestExampleThree(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_one(self):
            time.sleep(4)
            self.assertEqual(1, value)
    ```
- install `nose` test runner:

  ```
  pip install nose
  ```
- install `nose-timer` plugin:

  ```
  pip install nose-timer
  ```
- run the tests:

  ```
  $ nosetests test_nose --with-timer
  ....
  test_nose.test3.TestExampleThree.test_one: 4.0003s
  test_nose.test3.TestExampleTwo.test_one: 3.0010s
  test_nose.test2.test_one: 2.0011s
  test_nose.test1.TestExampleOne.test_one: 1.0005s
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 4 tests in 10.006s

  OK
  ```

The result is actually conveniently highlighted:
[image: nosetests results]

The coloring can be controlled by `--timer-ok` and `--timer-warning` arguments.

Note that `time.sleep(n)` calls were added for making the manual slowdowns to see the impact clearly. Also note that `value` variable is set to `1` in "setup" functions and methods, then in test function and methods the `value` is asserted to be `1` - this way you can see the work of setup functions.

UPD (running `nose` with `nose-timer` from script):

```
from pprint import pprint
import nose
from nosetimer import plugin

plugin = plugin.TimerPlugin()
plugin.enabled = True
plugin.timer_ok = 1000
plugin.timer_warning = 2000
plugin.timer_no_color = False


nose.run(plugins=[plugin])
result = plugin._timed_tests
pprint(result)
```

Save it into the `test.py` script and pass a target directory to it:

```
python test.py /home/example/dir/tests --with-timer
```

The `result` variable would contain:

```
{'test_nose.test1.TestExampleOne.test_one': 1.0009748935699463,
 'test_nose.test2.test_one': 2.0003929138183594,
 'test_nose.test3.TestExampleThree.test_one': 4.000233173370361,
 'test_nose.test3.TestExampleTwo.test_one': 3.001115083694458}
```

Comment: This is exactly like what I'm looking for.  I'm gonna test it out on Monday and get back to you with any questions - will accept then.  Thank you.

Comment: I need to be able to get those values for run times into a module so I can store them and put them in a nice graph with comparisons to previous tests.  How exactly might I go about doing that?

Comment: In other words, how can I run `nosetests test_nose --with-timer` from a Python module and get those run times into some kind of list?

Comment: @weskpga updated the answer. See the `UPD` section. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, that's perfect.  One last question now: how would I pass in the absolute path for a directory to be run with this script?  Would I do it like `nose.run(argv=['home/example/directory/here', '--with-timer'], plugins=[plugin])`?  I accepted your answer since you've already been so much help.

Comment: @weskpga the way you are showing should work. Let me know if there are problems with it. Thanks.

Comment: Does `home/example/directory/here` represent a relative or absolute path in terms of where nose will look?  I need to be able to pass in an absolute path.

Comment: @weskpga as far as I understand it is relative. If you want an absolute, use `/home/example/directory/here`, watch the leading slash.

Comment: Is `nosetests /home/example/dir/tests --with-timer` from the command line not the same as `nose.run(argv=['/home/example/dir/tests', '--with-timer'], plugins=[plugin])` ran in python?  Because the first yields all the test results I want, while the second doesn't seem to yield anything.

Comment: @weskpga i see what you mean. I've updated the example, please check.

Comment: Running `python find_and_benchmark_tests.py /home/example/dir/tests --with-timer` now gives: `OSError: No such file /home/example/dir/tests`, even though it's identical to the successful tests I'm able to run with `nosetests /home/example/dir/tests --with-timer`.  Any idea what might be going on?  Sorry to keep bothering you - I appreciate your patience.

The error is here: `File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 41, in runTest
    raise self.exc_class(self.exc_val)`