# Timing a unit test, including the set up

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

How can you capture the time of an individual unit-test, including the set-up cost?

I've got a test base with a set-up procedure which takes a non-trivial amount of time to complete. I've got several tests which descend from that test base, and I've got a decorator which, in theory, should print out the time it takes to run each test:

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # some setup procedure that takes a long time

def timed_test(decorated_test):
    def run_test(self, *kw, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        decorated_test(self, *kw, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print "test_duration: %s (seconds)" % (end - start)
    return run_test


class TestSomething(TestBase):
    @timed_test
    def test_something_useful(self):
        # some test
```

Now, when I run these tests it turns out that I'm only printing the time it took for the test to run *not including the set-up time*. Tangentially, a related question may be: is it best to deal with timing outside of your testing framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not reinvent the wheel and use [`nose`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test runner with [`nose-timer` plugin](https://github.com/mahmoudimus/nose-timer):

> A timer plugin for nosetests that answers the question: how much time
>   does every test take?

See more about `nose-timer` here:

- [How to benchmark unit tests in Python without adding any code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150016/how-to-benchmark-unit-tests-in-python-without-adding-any-code)

Comment: Yeah, this is actually a fantastic response... I've been avoiding adding stuff to our requirements.txt, but at a certain point it seems my time would be better spent convincing someone to include nose than to circumvent another pip. Thanks!